# Avoid losing commit message when committing fails

Tags: git

A pretty frequent scenario for me is writing a long, thoughtful commit message, then fat-fingering my smartcard PIN.

```
% git commit
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

After this when running `git commit` again the message is lost. Is there a way to have Git remember the previous message?

Comment: Similar question on Unix StackExchange: [Is git commit message recoverable if committing fails for some reason?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/590224/is-git-commit-message-recoverable-if-committing-fails-for-some-reason)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution I have found so far is that after a failed commit (actually after any commit) the commit message file (including any extra info that would be stripped from the message) is left over in `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG`. You can save that file **before** running the next `git commit` and paste it into the new message.

Note that this file will be **overwritten as soon as you run `git commit` another time**. So be sure to save it before starting the second commit attempt.